# Metamask not returning to original url

Tags: reactjs, web3js, metamask

I have connected an app in react js with metamask through deeplinking and I am able to successfully get the user wallet address but then the metamask is not redirecting to the original URL on my webpage.
below is the link to a video, site url and an image where connecting to MetaMask on click.
CHECK ISSUE ON SITE => http://deknow-staging.herokuapp.com/

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LwGcQLYnZ6mzoKZQCduycC8kfwUfqGAt/view?usp=sharing

[image: Code for opening app to connect]

below is the code where we check if wallet is connected or not if not then will connect it with connect() function.

```
async function checkIfWalletIsConnected() {
if (window.ethereum) {
  const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
    method: "eth_accounts",
  });

  if (accounts.length > 0) {
    const account = accounts[0];
    accountChangeHandler(account);
    return;
  }

  if (mobileCheck()) {
    await connect();
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Pleae edit your issue and add more details. The question as is poor quality, even though the problem is real. It does not have enough details for anyone to help you or understand the problem. Include screenshots, relevant bits of source code and so on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated the information, Please now  if you can answer this.